ffmpegで複数枚の画像をfade-inしながらoverlayしたい
作業用フォルダに以下のファイルがあります。(すべてサイズは400×400)

text1.png
text2.png
video.mp4

このvideo.mp4にtext1,text2をフェードインしながらオーバーレイしたいと考えています。
1枚だけなら下記のコードでできましたので、下記コードに改良を加える形で研究しております。
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -loop 1 -i text1.png -filter_complex "[1]fade=in:st=2:d=1:alpha=1[i];[0][i]overlay=x=0:y=0:shortest=1;" output.mp4

マニュアルやググった情報などを元に作ってみたコードが下記です。
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -loop -i text1.png -i text2.png -filter_complex "[1]fade=in:st=2:d=1[i];[2]fade=in:st=2:d=1[y];[0][i]overlay=x=0:y=0:shortest=1[v1];[v1][y]overlay=x=0:y=0[v2]" -map "[v2]" output.mp4

しかしこれだとInvalid file index 2 in filtergraph description とエラーになり、2枚目の画像が無効になります。
2枚の画像をoverlayするにはどのように改良すればよいでしょうか？
